# TheCartPress plugin - Make every item in store unique

Tags: plugins, php, e-commerce

I have been trying to figure out how to take the WordPress plugin TheCartPress have each item in the shop unique, so that quantity does not matter at all and is essentially disabled.

My research has led me to find only another request for this feature and no solutions...onto my (partial) solution:

I can hide the quantity adjustments and only allow users to add a single item to their cart at a time but they can come back to the page and add another copy of the same item. The only way I can think of to work around this is to use their cart to detect whether the add to cart button should be disabled on page load...that seems like it would work but maybe isn't the best way...any (better) ideas before I try to hack up this plugin? :D

example page: http://babushoe.cordslatton.com/product/paleo-clogs/

contents of getShoppingCart()

```
 tcp_session_start();
    if ( TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart !== false ) {
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['tcp_session_refresh'] ) ) {
            TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart->refresh();
            unset( $_SESSION['tcp_session_refresh'] );
        }
        return TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart;
    }
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['tcp_session'] ) ) {
        if ( is_string( $_SESSION['tcp_session'] ) ) TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart = unserialize( $_SESSION['tcp_session'] );
        else TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart = $_SESSION['tcp_session'];
    }
    if ( TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart === false ) {
        TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
        $_SESSION['tcp_session'] = serialize( TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart );
    }
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['tcp_session_refresh'] ) ) {
        TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart->refresh();
        unset( $_SESSION['tcp_session_refresh'] );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'tcp_get_shooping_cart', TheCartPress::$tcp_shoppingCart );
```

Comment: Search the plugin code for a function like `get_cart` or similar. If exists, you should be able to extract useful info from it.

Comment: I added the code for getShoppingCart, however it is a rabbit hole to go down...I was hoping to find a moderately simple way to do this...